# nested has_many through associations not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2, has-many-through

Running Rails 3.2.1.  Trying what should be a simple nested has_many through association as shown in the docs (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association):

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :locations, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :assets,  :through => :locations
  has_many :components,  :through => :assets
end

class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
  has_many :assets
  has_many :components, :through => :assets
end

class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :location
  has_many :components
end

class Component < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :asset
end
```

In the console `Company.find(2)` works fine as well as `Company.find(2).locations` but not `Company.find(2).assets` or `Company.find(2).components`.  I get:

```
1.9.3p0 :071 > Company.find(2).assets
  Company Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "companies".* FROM "companies" WHERE "companies"."id" = $1 ORDER BY name ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
NoMethodError: undefined method `assets' for #<Company:0x007f939d714318>
```

I seem to be missing something here.  I am nested one more level deep but according to the docs this should be ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow... was driving me crazy.  Hope I can help someone else with this.  Searched the console error message and all that was required was a console re-load... D'oh!